# Ethereum mining but not receiving rewards

Tags: mining, myetherwallet, mining-pools

I have been mining using NiceHash for a while now and decided I want to mine ethereum into my own wallet so I dont need to wait for the payout threshold. I copied the claymore miner out of nicehash 3rdparty folder. I then enetered my own settings into the start.bat file

EthDcrMiner64.exe -epool eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:8008 -ewal 0xcC261261d920ad5aa37CDFDeDBE4B076D22cA2c1 -epsw x

I launch it and it appears to work fine. I left it on for 12 hours to check my wallet which I created on MyEtherWallet.com to see that I had no balance.

Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far so good. If you check your balance at the pool, you'll see you haven't accumulated enough to get paid. No one said mining would me lucrative. Okay. Maybe some people did.

Edit: looks like you haven't been submitting shares for the last 7 hours, but I see your 12 hours of mining. Your payout is set to be once you hit an ether; that currently looks like it'll take you ~250 days to reach the threshold assuming you mine 24/7, difficulty does not increase, and mining hasn't been replaced by proof of stake.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. You are correct, dwarfpool's minimum payout is 1 ETH. As the whole point of not using NiceHash was to have a smaller minimum payout it, is their a ethereum mining pool that had a lower minimum to make it more viable, thanks

Comment: is it possible just to mine and withdraw in small sums, eg 4 USD at a time. This will allow me to mine at night twise a week to purchase a large bag of lollies at the dairy.

Comment: It looks like Dwarfpool allows you to request a manual withdrawal for your lolly run. But given that you seem to be getting $1 US/day, you'll need to mine for 96 hours at current prices and difficulty. That hourly rate is dropping fairly quickly due to increased network hash rates and the Ethereum difficulty bomb.